# Linux kernel make with headers from different driver tree

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, include, linux-device-driver

I am trying to include the gpu_ipa header from the mali driver directory tree in my 3.10.9 android kernel within my cpufreq module. I have been looking through the make files but cannot make sense of how I am meant to include the mali directories in the make config for my module, in the cpufreq driver directory.

Just to elaborate if not quite clear.

In my module (optigame_governor.c/h) I have

```
#include "gpu_ipa.h"
```

In my cpufreq makefile

```
obj-$(CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_OPTIGAME) += optigame_governor.o
```

no includes :(

The file structure between my module and the target header looks like

```
kernel---drivers---cpufreq---optigame_governor.c/h
                \--gpu---arm---midgard---platform---gpu_ipa.h
```

I am not 100% sure if this is the exact file I need but I will need something in this other driver branch and so am looking for a somewhat generalized solution.

Cheers

Comment: The instuctions to do this are in the kernel source Documentation directory.  See Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Comment: @stark i've been reading this and trying. Following section 4.2, by creating a Kbuild file to build just my module as the rest are built by the make file. Although thus far I have no had any luck.

Comment: I think you want something like this in your makefile: `ccflags-$(CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_OPTIGAME)    := -Igpu/arm/...`

Comment: Thanks @GilHamilton. I tried this, I have used the relative path 'ccflags-$(CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_OPTIGAME) := -I../gpu/arm/midgard
 obj-$(CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_OPTIGAME) += optigame_governor.o optigame_governor_sched.o optigame_governor_stats.o' but I still get the same include error :/

Comment: `make -n` will cause make to print out the full command it's using to compile your sources.

Comment: @GilHamilton, in kernel there is a special variable `make V=1` does the trick.

Comment: @GilHamilton was almost right. The relative path not always can be used,  though we have a possibility to specify an "absolute" one via **-I$(srctree)/...** I would highly recommend to search for examples in the kernel. And I also recommend to use `#include <platform/gpu_ipa.h>` instead (with path to the *platform* folder in **-I** directive).

Comment: Thanks @GilHamilton and @0andriy your input is priceless. I appended `ccflags-$(CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_OPTIGAME) := -Idrivers/arm/midgard` and included `#include <midgard/platform/gpu_ipa.h>` (as gpu_ipa.h requires files from midgard) but this resulted in error occurring the object after my module in the Makefile. Funnily enough after removing my Makefile changes, removing the include and running make clean or mrproper from the kernel root directory the errors persist :/

Comment: @GilHamilton ignore my problem with make clean, manual cleaning of the cpufreq directory solved it. Still can't build though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using the ccflags mentioned in the comments.

Adding

```
ccflags-$(CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_OPTIGAME) += -Idrivers/gpu/arm/midgard
```

to my cpufreq Makefile and adding

```
#include <platform/gpu_ipa.h>
```

to my c file solved the problem. Problem was due to not using absolute paths.